# Angular Unit Testing for HostListener (Window Resize)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component file that has below code

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.width = event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

I want to test it. I have tried with the below code in my spec file.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize");
expect(component.onResize).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved using a Spy on the function triggered by the resize event.

```
 it('should trigger onResize method when window is resized', () => {
    const spyOnResize = spyOn(component, 'onResize');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    expect(spyOnResize).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is still failing. "spy OnResize to have been called". Not sure dispatchEvent is dispatching resize event or not.

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee Can you share stackblitz link to check further ?